# Microsoft Graph SDK Java: How to get FileAttachment object in Java SDK which contains contentBytes?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to get contentBytes using Microsoft Graph SDK to download office mail attachments.

I tried the following but its giving ClassCastException. I dont know how to directly get List of FileAttachment object through Microsoft Graph SDK(Java)

```
IAttachmentCollectionPage aAttachementPage = clientAuthGraphServiceClient.users("#userIDGiven#").mailFolders("Inbox").messages(message.id).attachments().buildRequest().get();

for (Attachment aAttachment:aAttachementPage.getCurrentPage()) {
   String serviceDirectory="D:\\DOWNLOADS\\";
   File fileDown= new File(serviceDirectory+aAttachment.name);
   Files.write(fileDown.toPath(), ((FileAttachment)aAttachment).contentBytes);
}
```

I am using following jar:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
        <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For GraphApi version 2.5.0

```
AttachmentCollectionPage attachmentCollectionPage =
    graphClient
        .me()
        .messages(messageId)
        .attachments()
        .buildRequest()
        .get();

    JsonElement att = attachmentCollectionPage
        .getCurrentPage()
        .get(0)
        .getRawObject()
        .get("contentBytes");

        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(att.getAsString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Every once in a while I'm cursing at the Microsoft docs about the (most of the times incomplete) Java implementation and I spend longer than I want to on upgrading the client. So I'm copying my own answer here. May somebody find this useful.

As of microsoft-graph version 5.34.0 several things are no longer needed, like decoding, and you'll be ably to simply cast your object.

A convoluted way to get File/ItemAttachments:

```
List<Attachment> attachments = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            AttachmentCollectionPage mgAttachmentList =
                    graphClient.users(emailAddress)
                            .messages(mail.id)
                            .attachments()
                            .buildRequest()
                            .get();

            do {
                attachments.addAll(mgAttachmentList.getCurrentPage());

                // Check for next page
                if (mgAttachmentList.getNextPage() != null) {
                    mgAttachmentList = mgAttachmentList.getNextPage().buildRequest().get();
                } else {
                    mgAttachmentList = null;
                }
            } while (mgAttachmentList != null);

            attachments.stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .forEach(attachment -> {
                        try {
                            // attachment equals a FileAttachment
                            if ("#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment".equalsIgnoreCase(attachment.oDataType)) {
                                byte[] attachmentContentBytes = ((FileAttachment) attachment).contentBytes;
                                if (attachmentContentBytes != null) {
                                    // your own logic here
                                }
                            } else if ("#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment".equalsIgnoreCase(attachment.oDataType)) {
                                /*
                                 *  We need to convert each Attachment.
                                 *  If it's an ItemAttachment, we need to do another call to retrieve the item-object.
                                 *
                                 *  The standard call with expand option gives us an Attachment (again)
                                 */
                                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(attachment.contentType)) {
                                    Attachment attachment = graphClient.users(emailAddress)
                                            .messages(mail.id)
                                            .attachments(attachment.id)
                                            .buildRequest()
                                            .expand("microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item")
                                            .get();
                                    if (attachment != null) {
                                        // cast the object to whatever you need, in this example I retrieve the webLink
                                        String linkToMessage = ((Message) ((ItemAttachment) attachment).item).webLink;
                                        // your own logic here
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    log.info("Unknown attachment contentType for an ItemAttachment - Could not read attachment.");
                                }
                            } else {
                                log.error("Unable to read an attachment for mail.");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            log.error("Could not read attachment: '" + attachment.name + "' for message: '" + message.subject + ". " + e.getMessage(), e);
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Something went wrong while receiving attachments for message: '" + message.subject + "'. " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several derived types of attachment.

- File Attachment
- Item Attachment
- Reference Attachment

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/attachment?view=graph-rest-1.0

If any of the attachments are not a FileAttachment, then you will get this kind of cast exception.  You will need to test the type of the attachment before trying to cast it to a FileAttachment.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled upon this and thought I might share our solution. Watch out for NPE or IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions.

```java
    MessageCollectionPage messageCollectionPage = graphClient.me().messages().buildRequest().get();

    List<String> messageIdsWithAttachments =
        messageCollectionPage.getCurrentPage().stream()
            .filter(message -> message.hasAttachments)
            .map(message -> message.id)
            .toList();

    AttachmentCollectionPage attachmentCollectionPage =
        graphClient
            .me()
            .messages(messageIdsWithAttachments.get(0))
            .attachments()
            .buildRequest()
            .get();

    byte[] bytes = ((FileAttachment) attachmentCollectionPage.getCurrentPage().get(0)).contentBytes;
```